# Increment from 0 to n from a set of numbers a to b

Tags: c#

Example:

Starting number: 0

Finish number: 147

Choose a random number in the range 1-26.  Increment the starting number by this number, continually getting another random number until we reach the finish number.

That is, if we are at 137 it means the random number has to be between 1 and 10. When we reach 144, between 1 and 3 and so on. I've tried using modulo to no avail.

Example of code I've tried:

```
int start = 0;
int finish = 0;
int highest = 26;

while(start <= finish) {
    int modulo = start % finish % highest;
    int random = (new Random()).Next(modulo);

    start += random;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what you think you are doing; but `0 % x` == 0  and `x % 0` is a division by zero error, for all x.

Answer (score 3):

It is <strike>a lot better</strike> essential to move the Random instance out of the loop. Otherwise all your values except the last few will be the same.

To get a number in your your dynamic range, there is the Random method
 `Next(int minValueInclusive, int maxValueExclusive)`

```
int finish = 147; 

// untested
var generator = new Random();  // outside the loop
while(start < finish)          // stop when equal
{
    int range = finish-start;
    if (range > highest) range = highest;

    int random = generator.Next(1, range+1); 
    start += random;

    Console.Write('A' + random - 1);  // check
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My first observation of the example you posted, assuming it's an example that you actually tried, is that start

```
int modulo = start % finish % highest;
```

is going to result in a division by 0 error because finish is 0.

Secondly, I think what you want to replace that line with

```
int modulo = (finish - start) % highest;
```

It makes more sense for the first term to be the distance from start to finish, because that's the limit you don't want to exceed when you add your next random number.

Answer (score 1):

Within your loop, you need to logically run through these steps:

1. What current number am I at? (`start`)
2. How far am I from the finish? (`var distance = finish - start`)
3. Am I farther than 26 from the finish? If so, my max is 25. Else, my max is however far I am from the finish ( `var max = distance % 26 )` or you can use a full if statement if the modulo is confusing
4. Generate a new random number between 1 and `max`.

it would look something like this:

```
int start = 0;
int finish = 144;
int highest = 26;
var rng = new Random();
while(start <= finish) {
    var distance = (finish - start);
    var maxRange = distance % highest

    start += rng.Next(1,maxRange +1 );
}
```

(The modulo means you will be within 0 and 25 always)

Comment: This will <strike>never end</strike> throw an exception. Not that I tested my version...

Comment: Yeah you're right. Also, it will fail because maxRange will eventually drop below 1

Comment: isn't a homework problem. i wanted to increment from 0 to a unix timestamp and create a string of characters, that, when summing them equals to timestamp. i quickly realized that having a max limit of 26 (alphabet) is going to create an incredibly long string.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. A good way to increase the data you hold would be to skip Dec and use base 16. Or do you have to use decimals in your storage?

Answer (score -1):

This should work, just need a simple if in the loop. No modulo needed.

```
int current = 0;
int high = 26;
int rand = 0;
int range;

while (current != 147)
{
range = 147 - current;
    if (range < high)
    {
    high = range;
    }
rand = (new Random().Next(1, high));

current += rand;
}
```